# How does weapon power meter works?

Tags: beat-hazard

Weapon power meter seems charging and discharging randomly. For sure there is a logic behind, can you explain me how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weapon Power does not change (short of dying, when it resets to zero); it is a statistic 0-5, that works in addition to the VOLUME powerup.

As to the actual weapons your ship is shooting, that is based on the music you're playing -- loud, heavy instrumentation means you'll get full power screen-clearing guns, and slow, orchestrated sections you'll barely shoot more than a spoonful of pea-sized pellets.